# Frequent freezing issue 16.04

Tags: 16.04

Using 16.04 LTS, installed 2 days ago in new laptop. I am facing freezing issue however not using resource hungry packages.Using eclipse neon.2 with jdk8.latest kernel version is 4.4.Please help

output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
Subsystem: Fujitsu Limited. Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

**below attached screen shot of free -h command**

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: How much RAM? How much swap? In `terminal`, type `free -h` and paste that output into your question.

Comment: total ram is around 8GB, didn't create the swap area while installation because ram is enough.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Lack of RAM shouldn't result in system freezes anyway. If the system runs out of main memory it may kill applications and processes but it shouldn't freeze them. If you can continue to work after such a freeze could you please make a copy of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and run `sudo dmesg > ~/dmesg.log` shortly after one of them [edit] your question to include both of them? Thanks.